# Carbonized combustion chambers

Tags: cylinder-head

I just took one of my cylinder heads off to fix a leaky valve(s) and the combustion chambers look very carbonized. I hope this is not from oil getting into the chambers.

Present:

[image]

6 years ago, when I last lifted the heads:

[image]

It can perhaps better be seen on the bottom of valves.

Present:

[image]

6 years ago:

[image]

What do these carbonized deposits tell about the engine? It is a 2007 Tacoma V6 with about 150K miles on it.

Comment: Does the engine oil need topping up between services?

Comment: @HandyHowie it did but I also found another location that was likely leaking so not sure about how much was leaking where